# Quadratic First Order Difference Equation

Tags: recurrence-relations, z-transform

I'm studying a variant of the discrete Nerlove Arrow model
\begin{equation}
x_{t} = \lambda x_{t-1} + a_t
\end{equation}
which can be easily shown to be decomposed as
\begin{equation}
x_{t} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \lambda^k a_{t-k}.
\end{equation}
Here, $x_t\ge0$ can be regarded as goodwill, $a_t\in\{0,1\}$ advertising decisions, parameter $0<\lambda<1$ to model the decay or goodwill for each time period $t$.

I wonder if there is any similar or general solution to the following extension
\begin{equation}
x_{t} = \lambda_1 x_{t-1} + \lambda_2 x_{t-1}^2 + a_t.
\end{equation}
In the latter case, we have everything defined as before but this time $0<\lambda_1<1$ and $\lambda_2\in\mathbb{R}$.

I skimmed through some material online and thought that the $z$ transform could a be a possible approach to solve this type of difference equations but have yet to find material that directly answers my question without going into depth on $z$ transforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A closed form solution for such a non-linear recurrence is higly unlikely. The $z$ transform (or generating function approaches) work only for linear recurrences.

You can derive an asymptotic approximation by noting that if you disregard the linear terms, you get $y_{t + 1} = \lambda_2 y_t^2$, this hints at a solution roughly like $y_t = \lambda_2^{2^t - 1} y_0^{2^{t - 1}}$ if $\lambda_2 > 1$ and $y_0 \ge 1$. Guess your solution is $x_t = z_t y_t$, where $z_t$ is a more behaved correction factor, and work on that.

Comment: Thanks @vonbrand,I guess you are right that a closed form solution is unlikely. Appreciate your tips on how a related recurrence might be solved :)

Comment: If $\lambda_2$ is small (a correction factor?), it might be more fruitful to start with the linear equation's solution instead.